# How can you force jQuery Validate to show errors inside the form elements, instead of outside?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

Taking this basic example of jQuery Validate (see link below), how can you instruct it to show the error messages inside the form elements, where possible (obviously checkboxes wouldn't work)?

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you'll want to tailor it for your own form, but absolute positioning may help you here. For the example you cited:

**[Truncated] markup:**

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
 <fieldset>
   <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
   <p>
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     <em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
   </p>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cmxform p{position:relative;}
.cmxform label.error{position:absolute; left: 11.7em; top:5px; display:block; width:180px; /*Computed width of text input was 189px*/ overflow:hidden;}
```

Of course, this approach does have one major drawback, and that is that the error label will hang above (and over) what the user is typing. On the jquery.com example, I had a red "Please enter at least 2 characters" message over the first letter of my name as I was typing. To remedy this, you'd want to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cmxform input[type=text]').focus(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.error').hide(); // Hide the error while the user is typing
  }).blur(function(){
    if( !$('#commentForm').validate().element(this) ){ // Re-validate this element, show the label if still invalid
      $(this).siblings('.error').show();
    }
  });
});
```